# Error While Deleting - File Doesn't Exist

Tags: 16.04, delete

Somehow I managed to create a file on my NAS drive which contains a forward slash in the file name (i.e. '/').  I think this has caused a problem.

Now trying to delete this file gives me an "Error While Deleting - File Doesn't Exist" message.  I've also tried using the terminal to do this, but this gives me an 'input/output' error message.

[image: screenshot image]

Checking out various forums have suggested that it might be an issue with the hard drive itself and to run dmesg, I did so and the output was voluminous, but contained lots of sections that looked like this:

```
[130690.519285] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[130690.519290] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[130690.519292] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present - tray closed
[130690.519294] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 01 23 00 00 01 00
[130690.519296] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1164
```

Which doesn't look good at all.  I've used the various scans on the NAS drive (which is a WD MyCloud Mirror) but so far they have come back negative (admittedly I haven't run the longest ones yet).

Appreciate any ideas where I go now?  I guess formatting the drive is an option, but thought there might be a simpler fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So coming back to this question several months later.  I fixed the problem at the time by reformatting the entire NAS drive - there wasn't much on it, so no big deal.

However somehow I then managed to end up with exactly the same problem shortly after.  Not sure how, but I did.

Anyway I solved it.  Connected the NAS drive to a Windows machine, changed the name of the file to something sensible and it worked fine back on my Linux machine.  I appreciate this isn't exactly in the spirit of Ask Ubuntu, but it worked; so I thought I would share!

Thanks for the previous help though, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sr0 errors are your DVD drive. Not related to your file problem.

1. open a `terminal` from the Ubuntu dashboard
2. `cd {to_the_directory_that_contains_the_bad_file}`
3. try either one/both of the following commands to try and delete the file:

   ```
   sudo rm -i *00e12.avi
   sudo rm -i "Battlestar Galactica\/ Blood & Chrome s00e12.avi"
   ```

Report back.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  Both commands gave me similar errors:

`rm: cannot remove '*00e12.avi': Permission denied` and 

`rm: cannot remove 'Battlestar Galactica\/ Blood & Chrome s00e12.avi': Permission denied`

Comment: Did you forget the `sudo` in the commands?

Comment: I copied and pasted, so sudo definitely used.  Re-ran commands without sudo (just to see) and in that case it displays `rm: cannot remove '*00e12.avi': No such file or directory` and `rm: cannot remove 'Battlestar Galactica\/ Blood & Chrome s00e12.avi': No such file or directory`.  (I also tried to getting my sudo password wrong, just to check - and if you do that it tells you to try again).  Appreciate your help.

Comment: We'll try one more thing before I run out of ideas. IF you have an existing real folder called "Battlestar Gallactica", temporarily rename it to anything else (like HOLD_FOLDER), then try `rm -r "Battlestar Galactica"` (with the quotes). This should remove Battlestar Galactica and all files underneath it. Hope this one does it. Then if you DID previously rename an existing folder, you can rename it back.

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid no difference.  Renamed the folder and tried the new command (in fact all of the above commands).  If you are out of ideas, then thank you for trying to help.  I really appreciate it.  I will re-format the NAS - not the end of the world.  At least you have proven that I wasn't missing something obvious.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: More than welcome. Wish I could have done more.